# Как приделать multiprocessing к коду по парсингу картинок

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, multiprocessing

Узнал о том, как использовать мульти поточность, но не могу приделать модуль multiprocessing.

Код:

```
import requests
import multiprocessing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

storage_number = 100
image_num = 0

link = 'https://wallpaperscraft.ru/catalog/art/1920x1080'
link_image = 'https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image'

for i in range(1,storage_number):
    responce = requests.get(f'{link}/page{i}').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
    block = soup.find('ul',class_ = 'wallpapers__list')
    all_image = block.find_all('li', class_ = 'wallpapers__item')


    for image in all_image:
        aimage_href = image.find('a').get('href')
        url_image = link_image + aimage_href[9:-10] + '_1920x1080.jpg' 
        image_bytes = requests.get(url_image).content
        with open(f'image/{image_num}.jpg', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(image_bytes)
        image_num += 1
```

Попытка:

```
import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 



def multi_img():
    storage_number = 2
    image_num = 0
    link       = 'https://wallpaperscraft.ru/catalog/art/1920x1080'
    link_image = 'https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image'

    for i in range(1,storage_number):
        responce = requests.get(f'{link}/page{i}').text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
        block = soup.find('ul',class_ = 'wallpapers__list')
        all_image = block.find_all('li', class_ = 'wallpapers__item')


        for image in all_image:
            aimage_href = image.find('a').get('href')
            url_image = link_image + aimage_href[9:-10] + '_1920x1080.jpg' 
            image_bytes = requests.get(url_image).content
            with open(f'image/{image_num}.jpg', 'wb') as file:
                file.write(image_bytes)
            image_num += 1

with Pool(5) as p:
    multi_img()
```

Выдаёт мне:

```
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Python_project\Request\foto_wall_new.py", line 28, in <module>
    with Pool(5) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,   
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,      
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main      
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the    
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your 
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program     
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Python_project\Request\foto_wall_new.py", line 28, in <module>
    with Pool(5) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,   
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,      
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main      
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the    
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your 
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program     
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Python_project\Request\foto_wall_new.py", line 28, in <module>
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    with Pool(5) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Python_project\Request\foto_wall_new.py", line 28, in <module>
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,   
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    with Pool(5) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,   
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,      
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in __init__
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main      
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the    
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your 
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program     
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.    _check_not_importing_main()

  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main      
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the    
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your 
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program     
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\Владелец\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
PS C:\Python_project>
```

Хоть она работает, но ускорения 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну там же в ошибке написано, что нужно обрамлять вызов пула в конструкцию:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

А, кроме того, вы вызываете одну и ту же функцию без параметров, вообще никак не используя созданный пул. В общем, надо как-то так:

```
storage_number = 100
...

def multi_img(i):
   ...
   # for выпилить из функции, i будет приходить как параметр

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        p.map(multi_img, range(1,storage_number))
```